# Строка кода

Tags: post

```
if ($randStr == $_POST["str"] )
```

Moжно ли сравнивать простую переменную с глобальной переменой `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, клиент через форму передает данные только в виде строк (не берём в рассмотрение файлы). Скорее всего да, можно сравнивать. Может даже лучше использовать ===?

Comment: А если я дядька плохой? Приводите вручную в нужный вам вид (string, int, ...) и сравнивайте с помощью ===

Comment: Вопрос в чём заключался? можно ли сравнивать стринговую переменную с переменной в массиве пост. Ответ - можно, даже с помощью ===. А вот если инт хотите сравнить, то естественно, надо == использовать.

Answer (score 0):

да, но только сравнением как в примере "===" не пройдет если вы используете разные типы переменных, не могу точно сказать в каком виде переменные в POST, скорее всего текстовые.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST — это глобальный массив, указывающий на ячейки памяти, хранящие некоторые значения. Переменная — ячейка памяти, которая хранит некоторое значение. Они сравниваются так же, как и обычные переменные.